# Heat Map of Dimensional Stacked Matrix in R of Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, heatmap

I am not sure whether the figure I am trying to implement is called heatmap of dimensional stacking or not?
I just started working in this field

If possible, what could be best link to refer so that I can implement. BAsically its a Grid of a matrix having 4 sub-grids for sub-features like S1, S2, S3 and S4 for a particular every element of the matrix
[image: Stacked Heat Map]

Comment: I believe that you can find it yourself http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap

Comment: Can you provide some demo code?

Comment: @AlexFilatov What you have shown is simple 2-dimensional heatmap which can be easily created in R. What I want is very different, each element of 2 D matrix is again divided into 4 parts S1, S2, S3 & S4 as you can see in my question

Comment: @the_skua I plotted heatmap in R using ggplot2, but have no idea how to do this, don;t have even idea, what it is called in real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to make, I have made something similar.
Here is the fiddle link.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var cw = 300;
        var ch = 300;

        var participants = 2;

        var item_h = ch/participants/2;
        var item_w = cw/participants/2;


        var x_inc = cw/participants;
        var y_inc = ch/participants;

        for (x = 0; x < participants; x++) { 
            for (y = 0; y < participants; y++) { 



                ctx.fillStyle="rgb(50,255,255)";
                ctx.fillRect(x*x_inc, y*y_inc, item_w, item_h);
                ctx.fillStyle="rgb(0,255,0)";
                ctx.fillRect(x*x_inc+item_w, y*y_inc, item_w, item_h);
                ctx.fillStyle="rgb(255,0,255)";
                ctx.fillRect(x*x_inc, y*y_inc+item_h, item_w, item_h);
                ctx.fillStyle="rgb(255,255,0)";
                ctx.fillRect(x*x_inc+item_w, y*y_inc+item_h, item_w, item_h);

            }

          }
        }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hawkeye15/pf5urbaz/2/)